# C#: Reading field is faster then having duplicated function implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, jit

I have a situation where many objects of different types are constructed at the start of an App and are then invoked together using an abstract method.
Many of these objects have 1, sometimes 2, parameters that can be determined during construction. They affect part of what this object would do during invoking.

So, as I understand, when `objects[i].Invoke` (except in my case it's not just an array) is called, first the virtual table gets dereferenced. Then there is an additional `if` check.
Since the virtual table is a must, shouldn't it be faster to have two implementations of Invoke method to get rid of `if`? (memory usage isn't a concern)

Now, code duplication isn't nice. But I know that if I have generic `MyType<T>`, JIT will generate one version of `MyType` (and all its methods) for all reference types `T`, and one version **per** every value type `T` (even if they have the same size). I see it as a way to force JIT into generating two different Invoke functions, that only differ in the part where the `if` statement was.

I made a speed test, to make sure I'm not missing anything. And so far it seems I am:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;



var test_size = 1000000;
var exp_res = new int[test_size];
var got_res = new int[test_size];
var oa = new Base[test_size,3];

var rng = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < test_size; i++)
{
    var b = rng.Next(2)==0;
    exp_res[i] = !b ? Base.CalcRes1() : Base.CalcRes2();
    oa[i,0] = !b ? new T1_1() : new T1_2();
    oa[i,1] = new T2(b);
    oa[i,2] = !b ? new T3<T3_h1>() : new T3<T3_h2>();
}

var sw = new int[3].Select(_=>new Stopwatch()).ToArray();

//[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
void test_step()
{
    {
        // Shuffle random row, so that "oa[i,1].f1()" can't be
        // optimized into "((t2)(oa[i,1])).Func1()",
        // turning virtual call into non-virtual
        var i = rng.Next(test_size);
        var temp = oa[i, 0];
        oa[i, 0] = oa[i, 1];
        oa[i, 1] = oa[i, 2];
        oa[i, 2] = temp;
    }

    for (int sw_i = 0; sw_i < sw.Length; sw_i++)
    {
        got_res.Initialize(); // Reset to zero
        sw[sw_i].Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < test_size; i++)
            got_res[i] = oa[i, sw_i].Func1();
        sw[sw_i].Stop();
        // Test sanity + ensure "got_res[i] =" isn't optimized out
        if (!got_res.SequenceEqual(exp_res)) throw new Exception();
    }
}

// Dry run, to JIT-compile everything
// 10 times just in case
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) test_step();
for (int sw_i = 0; sw_i < sw.Length; sw_i++)
    sw[sw_i].Reset();

// Testing 1000 times, to average out the background noise
var test_count = 1000;
for (int i = 1; i <= test_count; i++)
{
    test_step();
    Console.Title = (i/(float)test_count).ToString("P");
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    for (int sw_i = 0; sw_i < sw.Length; sw_i++)
        Console.WriteLine(sw[sw_i].Elapsed);
}



void WriteMHnd(Type t) =>
    Console.WriteLine(t.GetMethod("Func1")?.MethodHandle.Value.ToString("X"));
WriteMHnd(typeof(T3<T3_h1>));
WriteMHnd(typeof(T3<T3_h1>)); // Same
WriteMHnd(typeof(T3<T3_h2>)); // Different

/**
// First 2 as the same
WriteMHnd(typeof(TT<Exception>));
WriteMHnd(typeof(TT<T2>));
// Second 2 are both new methods
WriteMHnd(typeof(TT<byte>));
WriteMHnd(typeof(TT<int>));
class TT<T>
{
    public void Func1() { }
};
/**/



abstract class Base
{

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public static int CalcRes1() => 5;
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public static int CalcRes2() => 9;

    abstract public int Func1();
}



// Test 1: Manually implement both possibilities
sealed class T1_1 : Base
{
    sealed override public int Func1() => CalcRes1();
}
sealed class T1_2 : Base
{
    sealed override public int Func1() => CalcRes2();
}



// Test 2: Save choice into the field
sealed class T2 : Base
{
    public bool b; // Isn't even marked as readonly
    public T2(bool b) => this.b = b;
    sealed public override int Func1() =>
        !b ? CalcRes1() : CalcRes2();
}



// Test 3: Use generic magic, causing JIT to generate
// two versions of the "Func1" function, like in case of Test 1
interface IT3_h
{
    bool GetVal();
}
struct T3_h1 : IT3_h
{
    bool IT3_h.GetVal() => false;
}
struct T3_h2 : IT3_h
{
    bool IT3_h.GetVal() => true;
}
sealed class T3<TVal> : Base
    where TVal : struct, IT3_h
{
    // Doesn't change anything
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
    sealed public override int Func1() =>
        !new TVal().GetVal() ? CalcRes1() : CalcRes2();
}
```

(targeting .Net6.0)

Immediately something's not right, because `T3` consistently takes ~1% less time than `T1`. I would expect JIT to generate exactly the same classes and methods as in the case of `T1`. Instead, it somehow found a way to optimize the generic case more than the direct one.
But at least `new TVal().GetVal()` does get turned into a constant, otherwise `T3` would be much slower.

But, contrary to my belief, `T2` takes ~15% less time than `T3`. How?

My main guess was that in the case of `T2` the virtual table is somehow skipped. But the row shuffling at the start of `test_step` doesn't seem to have an effect.
I also played around with `[MethodImpl]`, but didn't find anything interesting.

It seems that the simple solution of `T2` is somehow smarter than `T3`. But I doubt JIT can somehow remove the `if` from `T2.Func1`, so it should be possible to find a better solution than both `T2` and `T3` if I can understand what is happening here.

Comment: are you able to convert this test to benchmark dotnet? it will give you reliable insights into runtime and memory allocations to help understand the behaviour.

Comment: Have you profiled your code and determined that the performance slowdown that is occurring causes your software to fail to meet your non-functional requirements?

Comment: @CodeReaper there is 0 memory allocation during testing.
Anyway, `BenchmarkDotNet` only displayed everything I already knew. Though, in a more robust and thorough way. I can upload the code and results if you want.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I initially overlooked standard vs profiling, because it seemed to add unnecessary complications. But now I [compared outputs for my 3 tests separately](https://imgur.com/a/Z1sjsYu): (separate comments to have them start from new lines)

Comment: 1. In the case of T3 vs debugger can't distinguish between `T3<T3_h1>` and `T3<T3_h2>`. But, at least, `Func1` implementations do have different memory locations.

Comment: 2. In cases `T1` and `T2` debugger shows as if `Base.CalcRes*` functions are called directly from `test_case`. This seems like a promising lead, but there is no way `T1` and `T2` are bypassing getting the function pointer from the virtual table. This should be just a quirk of debugger display... Right?